# Win64 compiling package from source: "sorry, unimplemented: 64 bit mode not compiled in"

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Trying to install RMySQL on 64-bit Windows 7.

Using R-2.14.2 with Rtools214 and MySQL Server 5.5.

Read through several step-by-steps of RMySQL source installation.

Troubleshooting:
- Copied libmysql.dll to R-2.14.2/bin AND R-2.14.2/bin/i386.
- Copied libmysql.dll and libmysql.lib to MySQL Server 5.5\lib\opt.
- Entered MYSQL_HOME=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 into Renviron.site, saved to R\R-2.14.2\etc.

My instances of common problems:

> Sys.getenv('MySQL_HOME')
>   [1] "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\"
>
> install.packages('RMySQL', type = 'source')
>   Installing package(s) ...
>   ...
>   **RS-DBI.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
>   make:**  [RS-DBI.o] Error 1*
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'
>   ...

I'm guessing my problem lies in the '64-bit mode...' message, but I'm not sure.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just for the record, cross-posting to rhelp is deprecated in that community and especially so if you don't advise about that fact.

Comment: Would love to see someone tackle this problem. I circumvented it by moving my database workflow to a linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems installing RMySQl
so I installed  the package RODBC which works fine.
(make sure the MySQL driver is installed).

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this error message has anything to do with RMySQL, or any particular package.

On 64bit Windows, instead of the default PATH :

```
C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin
```

( gives the error `sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in` )

you might (quite reasonably) notice the MinGW64 directory alongside and try :

```
C:\Rtools\MinGW64\bin
```

but in fact it needs to be :

```
C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
```

Then of course, stop and start a new DOS window to pick up the new PATH.