# compiling glmnet failed in windows

Tags: r, glmnet

Since the R package glmnet doesn't provide binary for windows, so I have to compile it under my OS win7 64bit. How ever I got this error message:

```
gfortran -m64 -fdefault-real-8 -ffixed-form  -O2  -mtune=core2 -c  newGLMnet.f90
 -o newGLMnet.o
f951.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [newGLMnet.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glmnet'
```

I also tried to compile it under windows XP 32bit, but with 'configuration failed for package glmnet' error message.

Has anyone succeed compiling glmnet in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trevor Hastie posted this on r-help 12 hours ago:

"We are aware that glmnet_1.7.3 does not pass for windows
and are looking into the problem. It has something to do
with the gcc compiler being slightly different on
windows versus linux/mac  platforms. As soon as we have 
resolved the issue, we will post a new version to CRAN"

Answer (score 0):

On 64bit Windows, instead of the default PATH :

```
C:\Rtools\MinGW\bin
```

try :

```
C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
```

Then of course, stop and start a new DOS window to pick up the new PATH.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15221883/403310